# Only horizontally scaling responsive image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, scaling

Im working on a website, and now i want an image (img tag) to only scale horizontally. So it always has to take the full height. And when you adjust the screen it should stay in the center and crop the right and left sides. And without "stretching" the image.

For an example (it's the big left image in the slider):

http://reddle.nl/frankendael/beers/t-i-t-s/

I want to be a able to always view the full beer bottle.

Comment: put your code also

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I use that currently. But i want to be able to see the whole beer bottle in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.vc_inner {
    height: 100%;
}
.attachment-full {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

if you want fit for all screens,use min-height or max-height

Comment: also without stretching

Answer (score 0):

you must embed your image in a div with `width:100%` and `oveflow:hidden`. your image must contain its size, also the `div` must have at least same height as the image

Comment: a created a small code.pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLeQQp?editors=1000 , you have to addapt it for your needs

Comment: thanks very much, but the beer bottle on the image should also stay in the center.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. Since you didn't give all possible details, or any code, I'm just guessing that this might accomplish what you want:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* just to show the container for testing */
  box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x1000/daily'>
</div>
```

I chose to do this using flex-box, by giving the container full-height, displaying its content (the image) center/center, and giving the image a height of 100%. This crops out the sides when the box is too small, and adds blank space when the box is too large.

You can see a live version [at this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXMrWj). There are other ways to do it, but this one is fairly clean and well supported.

Good luck!, and if this isn't what you wanted, please update your question to be more clear.

Comment: thanks, gonna try to implent it, so far it looks perfect!

Comment: It works good, but im having some problems in Safari. It seems to stretch the image vertically (making it higher than the actual image)

Comment: I have it in action here: http://brouwerijfrankendael.com/t-i-t-s/ it seems to work in firefox, but not safari and chrome